# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

recently I had some problems with the gradle files so i made few adjustments to solve these problems and every adjustment led to a new error ,the current one is :
***Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.***

this is the gradle>build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        //classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:+"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the app>src>build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication_10"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And I changed the gradle version in "gradel-wrapper" file :

```
#Tue Mar 23 14:02:06 EET 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip
```

the gradle 4.1.3 in the first two files is the default value and I tried to change it to 6.8.2 (as in the gradle-wrapper file) but it throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `app/build.gradle` remove the `classpath` statements

```
dependencies {
    //classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it works! but in the future when I make new application should i do anything? like use the same gradle files? or this is a permanent solution?

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras Each application has own build.gradle. The content depends by what your are going to achieve. some app could require other dependencies for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think in your Appgradle file you have called classpath. It should be only added in Gradle file, not in-app Gradle file

```
dependencies {

//Remove these class path you will be good to go
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}